# Excel VBA Percentile using Application Function with multiple criteria

Tags: vba, excel, percentile

I have the below formula working fine over large ranges of data in Excel 2007.

In all cases Range1, Range2 and ArrayRange are the same start and end rows.

Working:

```
 =PERCENTILE(IF(((Range1=Value)*(Range2=Value2)),ArrayRange),0.9)
```

When I'm updating the formula within a macro, I can't seem to figure out the correct way to formulate the above using VBA.

Can anyone assist with the below?

Not Working:

```
90thPercentile = Application.Percentile(((Range1 = Value) * (Range2 = Value2), ArrayRange), 0.9)
90thPercentile = Application.Percentile(If(Range1 = Value,IF(Range2 = Value2, ArrayRange))), 0.9)
```

many thanks
Nik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use arrays like that in VBA. You'd have to use Evaluate and pass the formula string:

```
90thPercentile = activesheet.evaluate("PERCENTILE(IF(((Range1=Value)*(Range2=Value2)),ArrayRange),0.9)"
```